# How to solve webkitRequestAnimationFrame giving extremely high FPS

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, frame-rate, requestanimationframe

Today I've been trying to get myself acquainted with anything new HTML5 has to offer, in particular the canvas. I came upon the site www.html5canvastutorials.com and began following some of the tutorials and playing around with the code a bit in different browsers. When I got to the following example I noticed something odd in google chrome. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-oscillation-animation/

The webkitRequestAnimationFrame function is supposed to help reduce FPS (and thus CPU costs) when not actively on the site, for example when you go to a different tab. However, when I tried the example, I noticed that this does not always appear to give pleasant results.

- Google Chrome as active window, site on current tab: Get around 60
  FPS, great!
- Google Chrome as active window, on a different tab: Get
  around 1 FPS, very good.
- Google Chrome as active window, on my TV
  (used as second monitor), 120 FPS, odd, but no complaints.
- Google Chrome not as active window, but on a different tab, also around 1
  FPS or so, perfect.

Then the bad part:
If my site is on the current tab, but I have another window completely covering the google chrome window (say a maximized window for example), the FPS shoots up to around 2500 (and consequently maxes one CPU core).

Everything works perfectly normal when I try the same site in Firefox.

This fiddle's an example where it shows the average FPS since the last refresh: http://jsfiddle.net/kmKZa/55/
(I pretty much copied the code from the tutorial site)

I would like to know how I can prevent these scary CPU spikes if anybody has any ideas. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: I've seen similar with an more or less empty requestAnimationFrame function, looks like if Chrome thinks there is nothing to do it fires requestAnimationFrame like hell. You can check the param of requestAnimationFrame and if too early delay next call with setTimeout.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Chrome Version 25.0.1364.152 / OSX 10.8.2

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to simply cancel the AnimationFrame loop when you blur the window, and request it again when you refocus it.

```
var isPaused = false,
    animFrame;

loop();

$(window)
    .on('focus', function() {
        if( isPaused ) {
            isPaused = false;
            loop();
        }
    })
    .on('blur', function() {
        cancelRequestAnimationFrame( animFrame );
        isPaused = true;
    });

function loop() {
    //your crazy loop code

    animFrame = requestAnimationFrame( loop );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RAF automatically stop execution on "idle".
U don't need to stop RAF loop execution